# How to adding an Enter Key/Carriage Return to the Honeywell Barcode Scanner

Tags: web-application, barcode-scanner

I using the Honeywell Barcode Scanner in my web app, and user must press an "Enter Key" also known as a "Carriage Return" after scanned data.
Is there a way to add the ability to send the Enter key after scan barcode to this device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS describe in Honeywell technical support web site:
add/remove the Carriage Return (CR) or Horizontal Tab (HT) after each scan.

we can do this with scan bar-codes in configuration sheet that exists in this URL:
[How to add a Carriage Return or Horizontal Tab after each scan](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/servlet/fileField?entityId=ka02K000000DoGLQA0&field=File_1__Body__s)

[Honeywell Scanning and Mobility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ht2E.png)

tip: Before adding the desired suffix, scan the bar code ‘Clear all suffixes’ show in the above image.